# TouchID crash on some iPhone 5S devices

Tags: objective-c, authentication, swift, ios8, touch-id

My app crashes on some iPhone 5S device (only some) with the error:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Unexpected error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named
>   com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon) UserInfo=0x174461dc0
>   {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.CoreAuthentication.daemon}

The line which breaks the app is the following:

```
LAContext().canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil)
```

Is this an Apple bug?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you try restarting iPhone? Are you sure you have iPhone 5S?

Comment: The app is not crashing for me - just for some of my users

Comment: this is really weird!

Comment: I agree - that's why I posted it here

Comment: I'm having this crash only on iPhone 6. That too using for long time. Its working fine with iPhone5s. Really weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an iOS bug.  When an API returns a 4097 error, it usually means that the system daemon that was responsible for handling your request crashed.  You can look for crash logs from the device and [file a bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).